# Resumable transfer for btrfs send

Tags: backup, encryption, btrfs

I am planing to backup data via sending btrfs snapshots to an online storage. The storage is mounted as a LUKS encrypted container file on a cifs share.

Later transfers will be reasonably fast, but for the first one is 1,3TB, which, when I use tc to leave me with a reasonable amount of upstream, will take 23 days.
Now, in theory, my connection could handle that, but reconnections are possible. As far as I understand, this would force me to start all over again, if I just use

```
 btrfs send ... | btrfs receive ...
```

Is there any save, that is, resumable way to do this? I found buttersink, but it only seems to allow resume for S3.

Any ideas?

Feel free to use the comments to suggest a completely different solution. It is a Hetzner Storagebox (https://www.hetzner.de/de/hosting/storagebox/bx40). I have FTP, FTPS, SFTP, SCP (but not SSH and paramiko also doesn't work), Samba/CIFS, HTTPS, WebDAV access. The storage is not to be trusted with the unencrypted data. Free space on both sites is not excessive. There will be lots of changing smaller files, so duplicity without a regular full backup (that would take a month again) does not seem to be feasible. For the same reason, rsync would most likely be slow when comparing the local version with the one locally mounted from remote.
EncFS seems to be unsave, since the other side will potentially be able to gather multiple versions of a single file over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, your remote storage is exposed as a filesystem. I don't use `btrfs` myself but I *assume* the snapshots are equivalent to one large "full backup" file followed by a number of smaller "incremental" files.

On that basis I'd still go with `rsync` because it's restartable. You can't use its snazzy delta differences algorithm unless there's an `rsync` server available on the remote host, but you can tell `rsync` to assume the source file hasn't changed and to continue after a break from the byte offset it had reached:

```
test -t 2 && progress=--progress
rsync -av $progress --partial --append --sparse /path/to/source.img /path/to/remote/storage/
```

If you can usefully `gzip` your source file before transferring it, do so. (Neither `--rsyncable` nor `rsync -z` is relevant for what `rsync` sees as a local to local file transfer.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but your idea von btrfs is not accurate. A snapshot is basically a (in this case) read-only copy of the current filesystem, that does not take any space initially. Only differences are later written to the disk. Because of that, it is very easy to determine what to transfer for an incremential update. Especially, all the information is cheaply available in the source FS, which is good because reading the target is very slow compared to the size of the data. This also more or less also rules out plain rsync, because it would take forever to figure out the differences.

Comment: Also, any compression will not work, since a) i cannot run code on the target, so decompression happens on my machine again and b) the remote machine is not trustworthy and may only see encrypted data, which is not compressible.

Comment: @mcandril so these `btrfs` snapshots are like `lvm` filesystem snapshots? (You get to see a snapshot of the filesystem from an instant in time.) I still don't see why plain `rsync` isn't sufficient then. Regarding compression, why not compress and then encrypt? (But if compression isn't useful, then don't compress. Just like I warned in the last paragraph of my answer.)

Comment: If you meant to do this just for the first transfer, then you are right. Technically, my question ruled that out, because one of the preconditions was low lokal space, so I could not have the img locally first, but I made that space by now. Actually I already wrote a comment about that, and about using rsync for the first transfer, but I got delete in the course of the discussion with someone who vastly misunderstood the question and got snappy.

Comment: BTW, compression before encryption is already active as a feature of BTRFS. Didn't explicitly think of that until now, but it is good to keep in mind :)

Comment: @mcandril re the snapshots, if they are best viewed as a filesystem snapshot then `rsync` the "full", and thereafter use something like `rsnapshot` (which is effectively `rsync --link-dest`) to give you the future differences. My current preference is a variation of this into an S3QL deduplicating filesystem on top of S3 cloud storage. My current record is 26TB of data using only 4TB of cloud storage.

Comment: How does rsync now which files changed since the last backup? Does it compare a single timestamp that is stored somewhere, or does it look at all files individually? In the first case, I am concerned about the fact that the rsnapshot (in contrast to a btrfs snapshot) is not atomic, in the latter case, I am concerned about speed.

Comment: @mcandril time and size, by default

Comment: So it does look at every file every time. I am not very intrigued about the idea to occupy my (consumer) internet connection with scanning through 1,5TB of stuff, including some 10k-100k files in maildirs, if I can have the same locally, instantly, for free, from btrfs. So I still guess I'll somehow get the first, full backup there (e.g. by transfering the complete encrypted image with rsync) and then go with a non-resumable way for the incremental ones. The size of those is manageable, it will work in most cases.

Comment: @mcandril `rsync` looks at the directory information, not inside the file contents.

Comment: Ok, good to know. After everything is running, I can make a test and see how the differences in speed are. If I remember, Ill post it here. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

[`btrbk`](https://github.com/digint/btrbk) supports:

> Resume of backups (if backup target was not reachable for a while)

[`buttersink`](https://github.com/AmesCornish/buttersink)  supports:

> local btrfs file systems, remote btrfs file systems over SSH, or S3 buckets.

Or you can do it manually:

1. Instead of writing to a shell pipe via stdout, use the `-f` option to write `send`'s data to a file:
     `btrfs send -f outfile`
2. Use your favourite resumable tranfer method (eg `rsync`) to transfer the file
3. Use `btrfs receive -f outfile` to read the data from outfile instead of from stdin

Comment: what if the scenario is as follows: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/362395/any-chances-to-read-a-btrfs-snapshot-as-a-file

Comment: What about the `raw` target (`man btrbk.conf`) and rsync?

Comment: That will use twice the snapshot size. Same problem.